# Getting elements from the output of vectorassembler

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I need to get the output elements of a vector assembler as separate columns using the Java API.

```
VectorAssembler assembler3 = new VectorAssembler()
              .setInputCols(new String[]{"res1", "res2"})
              .setOutputCol("res3");

DataFrame output = assembler1.transform(sensordataDF);
```

res1 and res2 are both double array vectors. Can anybody guide me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The output dataframe will be sensordataDF with a new column called res3, but also it will still have columns res1 and res2.

Edit: Maybe could be done using spark.sql.functions split and casting the column to string, and then while separating, casting back to doubletype.

I use spark with python, but in java should be nearly the same

Example:

```
split_col = split(output['res3'], ',')

df = ouput.withColumn('first_data', split_col.getItem(0))
df = df.withColumn('second_data', split_col.getItem(1))
```

Comment: Edited answer. Hope it helps

Comment: The length of each split could be different so the above code does not work

Comment: what about convert to rdd, then flatmap separating by , and then convert to dataframe again